# Why can't I use speech to text on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I just added an extension to Chrome which would convert speech to text. I got it from this website: https://speechnotes.co. The extension works well on Google, Amazon and various other famous websites but Facebook does not allow me to enter text through speaking.

For example, this is what I spoke (  hello. how are you? ):

[image: Screenshot]

But when I try to post it, I get :

[image: 'Post is empty' message]

What's going on? Why can't I speak on Facebook but on nearly every other major website? Is there any way through which I can speak on Facebook as well?

Comment: Try removing Grammarly first and see if that was a factor.